# Is there an elegant way to decide only one time according to the user input?

Tags: c++, user-input

Recently, I tried to write a madule. In many parts of my code I needed to decide based on the user input. For Instance, I needed to choose my buffer type based on the user input 8 bits or 16 ones. I implemented this code and it did my job:

```
if (requestedbitsNumber == 8)
    mxMalloc(sizeof(unsigned __int8)*NumberOfElements);
if (requestedbitsNumber == 16)
    mxMalloc(sizeof(unsigned __int16)*NumberOfElements);
```

Now I am wondering is there an elegant way to define something like macros and others to decide only one time according to user input? Something like this:

```
if (requestedbitsNumber == 8)
    #define dataType  unsigned __int8
if (requestedbitsNumber == 16)
    #define dataType  unsigned __int16
```

and use `datType` whereever it needs. I know the `#define` is preprocessor directive and used before the code is even compiled.
I used it only to show what I mean. Thanks.

Comment: Instead of "storing" the data type, you could just have some `size_t` variable that you set to `sizeof(unsigned __intX)` (where X is the right number). Alternatively, just do `mxMalloc(requestedbitsNumber / 8 * NumberOfElements);`.

Comment: You are correct where I create my buffer. But what about where I need to cast a void pointer to a specific type one. Something like `myUin16Pointer = (unsigned __int16*) myVoidPointer;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `template<class YourIntegerType>`.

So you write something like:

```
if (requestedbitsNumber == 8)
    X<unsigned __int8>();
if (requestedbitsNumber == 16)
    X<unsigned __int16>();
```

You can implement X as a function or a class.

---

To cast pointer you can write something inside X:

`pointerToInteger = (YourIntegerType *) myVoidPointer;`

Comment: Can you please explain how I can cast a void pointer to a specific type one by means of your suggestion?

Comment: I need pointer casting to pass arguments to my function. Suppose that I have a function like: `myFunction((unsigned __int16*) myVoidPointer)`. How  to use `X` to do that? I am sorry if it is trivial. I am newbie.

Comment: @GmtK implement `myFunction` as a member function of class `X`.